# How to return a character as a list in lisp

Tags: common-lisp

```
(defvar str "abcd")
(print (char str 2))
```

I've written this above but it does not return a list. its output is as follows

```
#\c
```

What I need it to return is

```
(c)
```

How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: `#\c` is a character in Common Lisp. `c` would be a symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really want `(c)`?

```
(defvar str "abcd")
(list (intern (string (elt str 2))))
;; returns: (|c|)
(list (string (elt str 2)))
;; returns: ("c")
(list (intern (string-upcase (string (elt str 2)))))
;; returns: (C) ;;  this is the closest
```

Comment: Why does it return |c| when its not converted to uppercase?

Comment: Because that is Lisp's convention. Actually Lisp converts all symbols and functions to upper case (so that in the REPL you can more easily see what is the "Answer" by the interpreter/compiler - if deviating from this, it prints this symbol name between the `| |`s.

Comment: |...| is a way to print the symbol's name readably, in case the outputted name would not be read identically. This happens here because the default readtable upcases symbol names, but if for example you changed the default radix for numbers to hexadecimal, the symbol bee would need to be quoted in |...| to avoid confusion with the number #xbee